# Get admob adaptive banner height on unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

So, here is my problem. Adaptive banners don't seem to have a function to determine his height after it load. I need that to calcule the positions of my objects on screen.

Tries that I made:

```
bannerView.GetHeightInPixels();
```

On emulator always return 100, which is very wrong, I believe because there is some scale applying to the object.

Next, I tried to check the banner width, to calculate the scale and apply that to height:

```
float scale = Screen.width/bannerView.getWidthInPixels();
```

But the bannerView.getWidthInPixels() always returns 0.

then, I tried to find the gameobject while the game runs, get his properties and try to calculate his height. I find the GameObject "ADAPTIVE(Clone)", manage to find his scale, and applying that to the bannerView.GetHeightInPixels(): Voilá.

```
    GameObject adaptive = GameObject.Find("ADAPTIVE(Clone)");
    float scale = adaptive.transform.localScale.y;
    float height = scale * bannerView.GetHeightInPixels();
```

But when running the final version on my device, the gameobject "adaptive(clone)" is simply not found. I tried various methods to find the gameobject on the build running on the phone and none worked. There is a way to hide the gameobjects (and admob makes that)?

So, I kind of have 2 questions:
1: how to discover the real height of the banner and
2: why seems that nobody is interested in that? because I was not able to find a solution by searching for 4 days, and it looks like a really big thing.

I'm using unity 2021.3.30f1 and Google Mobile Ads for Unity 8.5.2.

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on this problem for days and found the solution.

You need to put this line:

```
bannerView.GetHeightInPixels();
```

After banner printing recorded.

If you are using Google Mobile Ads for Unity 8.5.2, you can put this line inside the OnBannerAdLoaded event like this:

```
// Raised when an impression is recorded for an ad.
    bannerView.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
    {
        bannerView.GetHeightInPixels();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I just happen to encounter this problem, and as you did, i can not figure it out. But there is one thing that i can explain to you: in unity editor, the ‘ADAPTIVE(Clone)’ is a prefab, there is no doubt that you can find this game object. However, in a real android device, the banner itself is created by the android, that's why you can not find this game object(it's not a game object in unity anymore!). Anyway, i am still struggling in the same question that you had. Have you found a good solution?

--- barrier ---

After a peroid of time, I found a solution that works for me. First and foremost, we can get two numbers from 'bannerView.GetWidthInPixels()' and 'bannerView.GetHeightInPixels()'(named A and B here). Then we can make a game object whose width is fill with the screen width. So we get the third numbers C by 'gameObject.GetComponent().rect.width'. Now with these three numbers, we can calculate the number D we want(which stands for the banner height in Unity), just solve this equations 'A / B = C /D'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: actually, it seems that on build app, real device, the GetHeightInPixels() return a true value that can be used. I just posted an update on the app, and it seems to work fine, no complains yet...